# Jquery .submit with function handler doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm struggling with the .submit() function of JQuery. I'm calling the submit whe a button is pressed, because I have to make some control before actually submitting the form. The problem is that the funtion handler doesn't get called properly. In fact, if i try to call the function submit without a function handler works, but with it no.

```
$(function(){
    $(".subBtn").click(function(){
        var data=$(".data-torneo").val();
        if(data==""){
            $('.error-data').empty().text("Inserisci una data!");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            var check=$('input[type=radio][name=r-button]:checked').val();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            if(check=="fisico"){
                
                var strutt=$('.selected.strutture').text();
                if(strutt!==" Seleziona una Struttura"){
                    xhr.open('GET', '../TournamentControl?action=validateTorneo&datatorneo='+data+'&struttura='+strutt, true);
                    xhr.send();
                }
                else{
                    $('.error-struttura').empty().text("Inserisci una struttura!");
                }
            }
            else if (check=="on-line"){
                xhr.open('GET', '../TournamentControl?action=validateTorneo&datatorneo='+data, true);
                xhr.send();
            }
            
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log(data);
                    var tipo=data['0'];
                    var errore=data['1'];
                    if(tipo=="null"){
                        //$('form').submit();
                        $('form').submit(function(event){
                            alert('faccio la submit')
                            var struttura=$('.selected.strutture').text();
                            var fisici=$('number-box-tecnici-fisici').text();
                            if(struttura=="")
                                struttura="null";
                            if(isNaN(fisici))
                                fisici=0;
                            
                            $.ajax({
                                url :'TournamentControl?action=saveTorneo',
                                type:'POST',
                                data:'nomeTorneo='+$('.nome-torneo')+
                                     '&isHome='+$('input[type=radio][name=toggle]:checked').val()+
                                     '&gioco='+$('.selected.gioco').text()+
                                     '&mode='+$('.selected.mode').text()+
                                     '&organizzato='+$('input[type=radio][name=r-button]:checked').val()+
                                     '&data='+$(".data-torneo").val()+
                                     '&struttura='+struttura+
                                     '&numTecniciRemoto='+$('number-box-tecnici').text()+
                                     '&numTecniciFisici='+fisici
                            });
                        })
                    }
                    else{
                        
                        if(tipo=="data"){
                            $('.error-data').empty().text(errore);
                        }
                        else if(tipo=="struttura"){
                            $('.error-data').empty().text(errore);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Why are you using XMLHttpRequest instead of `$.ajax`?

Comment: Are you sure `if(tipo=="null")` is correct? Maybe it should be `if(tipo==null)`.

Comment: Your call to `$('form').submit()` creates an event handler that will run the *next* time the user submits the form. It doesn't submit the form then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the call to `$('form').submit()`. That's adding an event listener for the next time the user submits the form.

If you want to submit the form using AJAX, just call `$.ajax()` directly in the `xhr.onreadystatechange` function.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {
    let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(data);
    var tipo = data['0'];
    var errore = data['1'];
    if (tipo == "null") {
      //$('form').submit();
      alert('faccio la submit')
      var struttura = $('.selected.strutture').text();
      var fisici = $('number-box-tecnici-fisici').text();
      if (struttura == "")
        struttura = "null";
      if (isNaN(fisici))
        fisici = 0;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'TournamentControl?action=saveTorneo',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'nomeTorneo=' + $('.nome-torneo') +
          '&isHome=' + $('input[type=radio][name=toggle]:checked').val() +
          '&gioco=' + $('.selected.gioco').text() +
          '&mode=' + $('.selected.mode').text() +
          '&organizzato=' + $('input[type=radio][name=r-button]:checked').val() +
          '&data=' + $(".data-torneo").val() +
          '&struttura=' + struttura +
          '&numTecniciRemoto=' + $('number-box-tecnici').text() +
          '&numTecniciFisici=' + fisici
      });
    } else {
      if (tipo == "data") {
        $('.error-data').empty().text(errore);
      } else if (tipo == "struttura") {
        $('.error-data').empty().text(errore);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you’re right. I’ve never used $.Ajax before, and it creates me problem. Thank you!